# uiswitchview view with tag showing null

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I have a uiswitch view in a static table. I am trying to retrieve it via its tag in the viewdid load method. For some reason it always shows null. I do it with the viewWithTagMethod.

```
 UISwitch* switch = (UISwitch*)[self.view  viewWithTag:tag];
 [switch setOn:[value boolValue] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static table view contents are not loaded until after the super implementation of `viewWillAppear:animated:` has been called. Move your code to a later point and you should be fine. Alternatively, just use an outlet.

Comment: I was writing my answer saying you should use an outlet and "mySwitch.isOn" to get the switch value.

Comment: its still showing null :(. I tried both viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear

Comment: @rdurand I have a set of switches so i thought i would just set a tag for each one of them instead of creating an outlet for all.

Comment: @VBK have you called the super implementation first?

Comment: i managed to find my mistake. I was storing the tag properly. But you have to put it in the viewDidAppear function. Unfortunately this means you actually see the movement of the control.

Comment: Just don't animate the setting - then it will update instantly. `animated:NO` or just `switch.on = ...`